# Ascending order on assembly sorted output

Tags: linux, assembly

I'm working on a project for my Assembly Language class and I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong and why my code is being outputted as reversed order and why I'm having the -1 answer displayed as an output.

Here are the instructions for the project:

> This final version should read in all values and AFTER the -1 is
>   entered, it should display all of the numbers entered followed by
>   printing out the sum of these numbers. The stack must be used for this
>   program.

Here is my code so far:

```
START: READ X
PUSH
LOAD X
STACKW 0
LOAD Z
ADD 1
STORE Z
LOAD X
BRNEG OUT
BR SV

SV: LOAD Y
ADD X
STORE Y
BR WAIT

WAIT: NOOP
BR START

OUT: LOAD X
ADD 1
BRZERO EH
BRNEG SV

EH: STACKR 0
STORE W
WRITE W
POP
BR ENDOUTCOUNT

ENDOUTCOUNT: LOAD Z
SUB 1
STORE Z
LOAD Z
BRZERO END
BR EH

END: WRITE Y
NOOP

STOP
Z 0
Y 0
X 0
W 0
```

Here is my current output:  I'd like to ***display the output numbers in ascending order and also hide the -1 as the output***. All help would be appreciated.
[image]

Comment: You should detail which chip type your assembler is for (given the Linux tag, it might be x86_64 or i386, but it could be for any of a large number of other platforms too).  It isn't clear to me that Bash had anything to do with it.  It's not clear from the instructions whether you're expected to grow the array of values read by storing them on the stack — it's what a casual read suggests.  I'm glad to be able to say "I don't know assembler any more" (I once could code M68020 assembler, and M6502, Z80, M6809, but that was 30 years or more ago), so I can't help much more.

Comment: So it's currently doing what the instructions state, which is to make it display all the numbers followed by the -1, but I just don't know why the output is being displayed reversed.

But I do appreciate all the help that you've contributed so far.